# Internal SD card reader not mounted/detected lenovo y50

Tags: sd-card

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my lenovo y50. The only problem I am currently having is that the internal SD card reader, which is just meant to provide access to a 256 gb micro sd card, seems to return an error reading

Unable to access “268 GB Volume”

```
Error mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 at /media/bluntk0nkussi0n/C011-6AAC: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/mmcblk0p1" "/media/bluntk0nkussi0n/C011-6AAC"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

I have tried to find a solution using Google, but there was little to find on how to solve this problem, and the solutions I've tried did not work. There is no external problem because everything works fine in Windows 10.

Comment: It is unlikely that you searched anything. Entering "Ubuntu exfat" in google gives you the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Comment: I suggest you expand on your answer - why is that needed?

Comment: @guntbert There is a dozen of good answers on that topic. You can find one and mark this as a duplicate.